# is it more efficient to use ghosted vector in PETSC for PDE solving on unstructured mesh?

Tags: petsc

In a traditional PDE solver on unstructured meshes, we know exactly the sparse pattern of the Jacobian matrix, and we know that the amount of data to communicate is far smaller than the amount of local data.

Then is it more efficient to use ghosted PETSC Vec (created with `VecCreateGhost` or `VecCreateGhostWithArray`) than the default Vec (creatd with `VecCreateMPI`)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`VecGhost` can be useful if copying the interior values as part of a global-to-local (halo update) is expensive. The memory access pattern of a dedicated local vector can give better cache reuse, so perceived benefits of `VecGhost` are often erased in traversal. Also, since `VecGhost` contains storage for the ghost values, it typically increases the memory used by a Krylov space (relative to normal vectors, where there are a constant number of local vectors).

`VecGhost` is a dubious performance optimization; I don't recommend using it in new code unless you have done the profiling for your application and are sure that it is beneficial. It exists so that users who desire that particular optimization don't need to roll their own implementation.